# How do you document QFlags with doxygen?

Tags: c++, qt, doxygen

I have something like this (example from the [QFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qflags.html) documentation):

```
public:
//! Enum doc
enum Option {
    NoOptions = 0x0, //! Value doc
    ShowTabs = 0x1,
    ShowAll = 0x2,
};
Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(Options, Option)
```

Now I can document `Option` and its values, and they will be displayed nicely by doxygen. But I cannot make doxygen generate anything for `Options`.
In the Qt documentation it looks like [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationState-enum), they add a note at the top and the bottom of the enum's documentation, and they list it as a separate type in the index section.

More importantly, Qt is able to link to the QFlags where it is used as a function parameter (e.g. [QObject::findChild()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qobject.html#findChild)). Doxygen generates the function signature, shows all the parameters, but does not link the flags type. Can I achieve this somehow?

Comment: Did you try something with `PREDEFINED` like: `PREDEFINED             = "Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(x,y)=x;"` and setting `MACRO_EXPANSION` to `YES`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [albert's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48438445/how-do-you-document-qflags-with-doxygen#comment87365056_48438445), I was able to make the QFlags type appear in the documentation by doing this:

In the Doxyfile:

- Set `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES`
- Set `MACRO_EXPANSION = YES`
- Set `PREDEFINED += "Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(flagsType,enumType)=typedef QFlags<enumType> flagsType;"`
  or if you prefer to have it show up as an `enum` instead of a `typedef`:
  `PREDEFINED += "Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(flagsType,enumType)=enum flagsType {};"`

Then you can document the `Q_DECLARE_FLAGS()` invocation like normal:

```cpp
//! Enum doc
enum Option {
    NoOptions = 0x0, //! Value doc
    ShowTabs = 0x1,
    ShowAll = 0x2,
};
//! QFlags type for \ref Option
Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(Options, Option)
```

---

Regarding the note on the `enum` itself like the Qt docs have it:
I don't think it is possible to have this inserted automatically but you can write an [alias](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html) and then insert that into the documentation of the `enum` manually like this:

In the Doxyfile:

```
ALIASES += qFlagsNote{2}="<p>The \1 type is a typedef for QFlags\<\2\>. It stores an OR combination of \2 values.</p>"
```

In the C++ code:

```cpp
/*! Enum doc
 * \qFlagsNote{Options,Option}
 */
enum Option {
    NoOptions = 0x0, //! Value doc
    ShowTabs = 0x1,
    ShowAll = 0x2,
};
```

will produce:

> The Options type is a typedef for QFlags<Option>. It stores an OR combination of Option values.